# CodeSigning an IPA file using only Windows

Tags: ios, delphi, openssl, code-signing, x509

For a future project I need to learn how works the codesigning process for Apple iOS IPA files (iPhone/iPad).
The goal of my project will be to build (in Delphi) a Windows tool to codesign one IPA file (previously compiled with "*Don't Code Sign*" via XCode).

One sure thing, it's that is possible to codesign an IPA file only on Windows ; like Adobe does with AIR/Flash CS5. Also, Epic Games, Inc. built the UDK (Unreal Development Kit) with a third party tool to codesign IPA files.

This last one was coded in C#/.NET, so I tried to explore the source-code to learn how the codesigning process works but, wow, the code is fairly evolved and even if there are significant similarities between C#/.NET and Delphi, I'm quickly in the blur...

The iPhonePackager from UDK is really close to what I want to do (with less features).

From my research : certificates and keys can be "generated" via OpenSSL in command-line ; Apple uses X509 certificates to codesign the binary (?) ; a component like *Bouncy Castle Crypto* APIs can be used to manage certificates.

An interesting article about the codesigning process from Apple : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2206/_index.html

Also I'll have to generate, the "*CodeResources*" ; the "*embedded.mobileprovision*" from the Mobile Provisioning file ; and the "*CodeSignature/CodeResources*" with the hierarchy of all files like :

```
<key>MainWindow.nib</key>
<data>GTBfZPINlJlD7HXjMRAKgfAztXU=</data>
```

**If you read so far, you should definitely have a headache :)** 
So, below are few questions to start...

Is it possible to re-sign a binary already compiled and signed with "*Don't Code Sign*" ?
Do you think my project is a really hard job... ?
Do you think it will be better for me to hire a developer ? I can have a budget for this project but ideally I would like to do it by myself of course... :D

Many thanks in advance for advices and/or suggestions.

Beny

Comment: Do some research on ldid, and see if that's available for windows. At the very least, it'd let you run your app on a jailbroken device.

Comment: Hi Richard. Yes I already built a simple packager for jailbroken devices, but the hardest part is precisely to codesign the binary... :s I'll make some research around the LDID from Saurik. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have written a tool to update the mobile provision and resign the IPA on Windows, the tool and its C# source code (licensed under LGPL) can be found [here](https://github.com/ROM-Knowledgeware/IPASign).

Comment: The code is beautifully written, and works with native .net on a windows machine without any dependency on other 3rd party tools. I have myself tried with a few ipas, and many of them worked after resigning. However, for a few ipas, i got IncorrectArchitecture & AppexBundleIDNotPrefixed error while installing on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a similar project, but I couldn't find the source files for the UDK tool, is it open source? If so, could you give me a link to it?

I can tell you the CodeResources file uses a sha1 digest in base64.
You can create using openssl:
openssl dgst -sha1 -binary  | openssl enc -base64

Comment: Thank you Fabio for your input. I'll give a try to OpenSSL DGST function ;) I'll keep this question in touch in future. Best.

Comment: What about the UDK signing tool? Do you have a link to the source code?

Comment: The UDK iPhone Packager is really nice, but a bit complex for me. Give a look here : http://shrtnr.us/9vi9ju

Comment: The UDK's iPhonePackager is a bit outdated, the source code is available here: https://github.com/Shinigami69/Ark-Dev-Kit_Source/tree/master/Engine/Source/Programs/IOS/iPhonePackager